# Redirect to another web service from web service

Tags: java, php, web-services

I have inherited a .php based web service. I don't know anything abut php. I need to make changes to this web service. What I want to know is, is it possible to make a call to another web service from a php web service. In this case, I can develop the update as a java web service, and the php web service will call my new java web service if needed.

So this would look like the following.

> client ---> PHPWS ---> JavaWS

the response will be returned to the PHPWS, and that will be returned to the client.

This way I make a very small change to PHPWS.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible, yes. Whether it's feasible / secure / easy, we don't know.

Comment: Why do you need the PHP in the middle ?

Comment: if there is no process inside PHP (just bypass) then you can use 304 Redirect .

Comment: What about creating the new features on the Java WS and handling the routing of legacy vs actual on front of them (API gateway / load balancer / proxy / nginx)?